# Data transmission through optical fiber and copper wire

Tags: optics, frequency, signal-processing, fiber-optics

I read the following in one reference: A copper wire (twisted pair), the link traditionally associated with low bit rate transmission, is still in use in the modern data centers transmitting data at 20 Gbit/sec. The secret? it does so only over a few meters (the bandwidth distance product is constant). My question: I know that optical fibers, for example, are used for high data rate transmission over long distances. High data rates means high bandwidth and high carrier frequency. According to the constant bandwidth distance constant principle, we can decrease the carrier frequencies used with optical fibers, and thus increase the transmission distance. My question is: can we use very low frequencies (in the range of kilohertz) with optical fibers to transmit data over very large distances? Of course the bit rate will be very low, but I am asking about the possibility to transmit very low frequencies over optical fibers.

Comment: Please don't cross post. This isn't a physics question anyways.

Comment: You mean like radio waves? Optical fibers don't carry radio waves

Answer (score 0):

Optical fibers offers best transmission around 1310-1550nm or 850nm of **wavelength spectrum** depending on type of fiber.

for lower frequencies, the **attenuation** reaches beyond 10dB per Km.

[image]

However there have been increasing trend of transmission of radio waves over fiber through **radio over fiber (ROF)** in certain conditions.